# How to increase MTU to 1500 on GRE tunnel

Tags: mtu, gre

For context

`141.95.xxx.88` = OVH node

`5.9.xxx.130` = Hetzner node

`164.132.xxx.0/28` = OVH IP block (GRE to Hetzner)

Hetzner GRE Setup:

```
ip tunnel add gre2 mode gre remote 141.95.xxx.88 local 5.9.xxx.130 ttl 255
ip link set gre2 up
ip route add default dev gre2 src 164.132.xxx.1 table 667
ip rule add from 164.132.xxx.0/28 table 667
ip route add 164.132.xxx.0/28 dev vmbr1 table 667
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i gre2 -j MARK --set-mark 667
ip rule add fwmark 667 lookup 667
```

Network config:

```
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 164.132.xxx.1/32
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        up ip route add 164.132.xxx.2/32 dev vmbr1
```

GRE config:

```
ip tunnel add gre2 mode gre remote 5.9.xxx.130 local 141.95.xxx.88 ttl 255
ip link set gre2 up
ip route add 164.132.xxx.0/28 dev gre2
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

Network config:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 141.95.xxx.88/27
    gateway 141.95.187.94
netmask 255.0.0.0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp
```

Right now the MTU tests run the highest I can achieve is 1472 MTU

How am I able to set this to 1500. The interface (OVH side) does support jumbo frames 9000 MTU

Comment: *"highest I can achieve is 1472 MTU"* you mean without fragmentation, or…?

Comment: I want to be able to externally ping 164.132.xxx.1 with 1500 bytes

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I do not want any fragmentation

Comment: https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-documents/gre-tunnel-mtu-interface-mtu-and-fragmentation/ta-p/3673508